# 'Faced it with a card of ten' reference

Tags: phrase-meaning, elizabethan-english

> A vengeance on your crafty wither'd hide!
>
> Yet I have **faced it with a card of ten**.
>
> 'Tis in my head to do my master good:
>
> I see no reason but supposed Lucentio
>
> Must get a father, call'd 'supposed Vincentio;'
>
> And that's a wonder: fathers commonly
>
> Do get their children; but in this case of wooing,
>
> A child shall get a sire, if I fail not of my cunning.

[Taming of the Shrew](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/taming_shrew/full.html)

What is **faced it with a card of ten** referencing in this text? I can't quite remember what it was but it was something along the lines of a game.

Answer (score 1):

From *[**A Glossary:** Or, Collection of Words, Phrases, Names, and Allusions to Customs, Proverbs, &c., which Have Been Thought to Require Illustration, in the Works of English Authors, Particularly Shakespeare, and His Contemporaries](https://books.google.com/books?id=vBJJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA248)* by Robert Nares, page 248:

> *TO* FACE IT WITH A CARD OF TEN. A common phrase, which we may suppose to have been derived from some game, (possibly *[primero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primero)*), wherein the standing boldly upon *a ten* was often successful. A CARD OF TEN meant a tenth card, a ten.

Also similar from *[The Dramatic Works of Ben Jonson: Printed from the Text](https://books.google.com/books?id=ksoyAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA566)* by Ben Jonson, Peter Walley:

> *A card o' ten*, is what we now call a *tenth card*, and the phrase "to face it with a *card of ten*," is to win it, or get the better of it. To this purpose Shakespeare:
>
> > *Tra.* " A vengeance on your crafty wither'd hide !
> > " Yet I have fac'd it with a *card of ten*." *Taming of the Shrew.*
>
> Which passage Mr. Warburton thus explains, that is, with the highest card, in the old simple game of our ancestors; so that this became a proverbial expression.

The suggestion that "ten" was the highest card can be found in Wikipedia, under the English version section of [Primero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primero):

> Each player receives 4 cards dealt in 2’s from a 40-card deck ranking K Q J 7 6 5 4 3 2 A.